# When I run reload a bash terminal using the source command, why can I not chain commands using &&?

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal

I just modified `~/.bash_profile` to include the following alias:

```
alias ngrep='grep -v grep'
```

I then went to an already-open terminal session and ran the following:

```
source ~/.bash_profile && ps aux | grep mysql | ngrep
```

The output was:

```
-bash: ngrep: command not found
```

However, I then immediately ran `ngrep` and it ran without errors.

I'm looking to understand Terminal better. Why can I not chain an alias I just added after sourcing the bash profile using `&&`?

On a Mac running Mojave, with the standard terminal and bash.

Comment: The usual answer to any and all questions about aliases in the freenode #bash channel is "if you have to ask, use a function instead". I stand by that advice. :)

Comment: (well, s/is/used to be/; the factoid is now less pithy, but still arguably expands to that gist; see the history at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias)

Comment: ...btw, in the future, consider our sister site [unix.se] for questions that are pertinent only to interactive use and not to script development. (Aliases are only specified in the "user portability" optional annex/extension to the POSIX sh standard, and aren't honored in shell scripts *at all* unless one goes to trouble to enable them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aliases are simple prefix substitutions that take place **before** syntax is parsed. This gives them powers other constructs don't have (albeit powers which are rarely needed or appropriate) -- you can alias something to content that's subsequently parsed as syntax -- but it also constrains them: Because a compound command needs to be parsed before it can be executed, the `ngrep` command is parsed *before* the `source` command is executed, so the alias is not yet loaded at the point in time when it would need to be to take effect.

---

As a simple demonstration (thanks to [a comment by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676103/when-i-run-reload-a-bash-terminal-using-the-source-command-why-can-i-not-chain#comment94211152_53676239)):

```
alias foo=echo; foo hi
foo bye
```

...will emit:

```
-bash: foo: command not found
bye
```

...because the alias was not in place when the first line (`alias foo=echo; foo hi`) was parsed, but *is* in place for the line `foo bye`. (The alias *is* in place when `foo hi` is *run*, but the command has already been split out into the command `foo` with the argument `hi`; there's no remaining opportunity to change `foo` to `echo`, so the fact that the alias is defined at this time has no impact on execution).

---

You wouldn't have this problem with a function:

```
# note that you can't run this in a shell that previously had ngrep defined as an alias
# ...unless you unalias it first!
ngrep() { grep -v grep "$@"; }
```

...doesn't require recognition at parse time, so you can use it in a one-liner as shown in the question.

Comment: So in slightly different words, `ngrep` will be visible in the current shell only after the `source` finishes, but the shell has to parse the command line before that happens.

Comment: An even simpler demonstration is `alias foo=echo; foo hi` (all one line).

Answer (score 0):

As an indirect solution, consider editing your match pattern. e.g.:

```
$: ps -fu $LOGNAME
     UID     PID    PPID  TTY        STIME COMMAND
P2759474    6704   10104 pty0     14:26:54 /usr/bin/ps
P2759474   10104    9968 pty0     07:59:11 /usr/bin/bash
P2759474    9968       1 ?        07:59:10 /usr/bin/mintty
$: ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep '/mintty$'
P2759474    9968       1 ?        07:59:10 /usr/bin/mintty
```

You don't have to `grep -v grep` if your `grep` already is specific enough to exclude itself.

Comment: That was mostly just an example, I'm just hoping to learn about why this works the way it does in bash.